# How to make different elements in enumeration have different functions inside a class in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, enums

I have an `enum` type `roles` like this:

```
enum roles { reader, librarian, dataManager, administrator };

class Role
{
public:
    Role();
    void setRole(roles roleID);
    roles getRole();
    ~Role();
private:
    roles roleID;
};
```

Supposed every reader has 2 functions of `searchForBook()`, `seeNotifications()` and every librarian has 2 functions of `add()`, `removeFromSystem()`.
What should I do to implement the above so that when it's done, the code may be like this (actually, this code doesn't work in C++, it is supposed):

```
enum roles { reader, librarian, dataManager, administrator };

class Role
{
public:
    Role();
    void setRole(roles roleID);
    roles getRole();
    switch (roleID)
    {
    case reader: //they have two functions to be used, I mean
        searchForBook();
        seeNotifications();
    case librarian: //they have two functions to be used, I mean
        add();
        removeFromSystem();
    }
    ~Role();
private:
    roles roleID;
};
```

Comment: Better choose to implement a _Decorator Pattern_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thank you.

Comment: Especially since it looks that one person could take more than one of these roles at the same time.